# Importing Android ContactsList sample project gives me somany errors

Tags: android, eclipse

[These are the errors i get when i import Android sample project ContactsList.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsbl.jpg)

I am new to android. I cleaned the project, Restarted the Eclipse  and all. But those are not going away. This is a sample project provided by the Android Doc's, so i think importing this project should not show any of these errors. I am unable to identify the problem with this. Can anyone tell me why am i getting these errors.

Comment: what version of android are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.3 version

Comment: Yes Mikel as you pointed out, it is a problem with the version of android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The problem is that my project is targeting to some older version of android. At first i tried changing Manifest.xml file **android:minSdkVersion="5"  android:targetSdkVersion="17"** properties. TargetSdkVersion is pointing to the higher versions initially though. Then I went to the properties by right clicking on the top level project folder name, and then i clicked on the Android menu, and there i changed the Project Build Target to the latest one. That solved my problem. Thanks for @Mikel for pointing that it is a version problem.

Comment: Ok, but be careful because if you install in a device with API 5 it will not work since those resources are only available in higher APIs. So be careful about your minSdkVersion.